Hardware keyboard focus never lands on Annotated string hyperlink in Jetpack compose
I have created an annotated string in Jetpack composable and assigned it to composable Text view. It has multiple hyperlinks.
The code is as below:
@Composable
    fun HyperlinkText(
        fullText: String,
        linkTexts: List<String>,
        linkUris: List<String>,
        linkTextColor: Color,
        textColor: Color
    ) {
        val annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
            append(fullText)
            linkTexts.map {
                val startIndex = fullText.indexOf(it)
                if (startIndex != -1) {
                    val endIndex = startIndex + it.length
                    if (endIndex > fullText.length) return@map
                    addStyle(
                        SpanStyle(
                            color = linkTextColor
                        ),
                        startIndex,
                        endIndex
                    )
                    val indexOfLinkText = linkTexts.indexOf(it)
                    if (indexOfLinkText != -1) {
                        addStringAnnotation(
                            tag = ANNOTATION_URL,
                            annotation = linkUris[indexOfLinkText],
                            start = startIndex,
                            end = endIndex
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        val uriHandler = LocalUriHandler.current
        var layoutResult by remember { mutableStateOf<TextLayoutResult?>(null) }
        Text(
            text = annotatedString,
            style = run { deviceTypography?.resolveStyle() ?: typography.resolveStyle() }.copy(
                color = textColor
            ),
            modifier = Modifier
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectTapGestures { offset ->
                        layoutResult?.let { textLayoutResult ->
                            val position = textLayoutResult.getOffsetForPosition(offset)
                            annotatedString.getStringAnnotations(
                                tag = ANNOTATION_URL,
                                start = position,
                                end = position
                            ).firstOrNull()?.let { stringAnnotation ->
                                uriHandler.openUri(stringAnnotation.item)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .focusable(),
            onTextLayout = { layoutResult = it }

        )
    }

When navigating using hardware keyboard, the focus never goes on the hyperlink of the annotated string. I am using jetpack compose 1.7.0. I tried mix and match of focusables and focusProperties in modifier, but nothing works. What could be the issue?

@Composable
fun LinkedText() {

val focusGuide = FocusRequester()


val textWithLink = buildAnnotatedString {
    append("Want to learn more? ")
    
    pushStringAnnotation("URL", "https://www.google.com")
    
    withStyle(TextStyle(color = Color.Blue)) {
        append("Visit our website")
    }
    
    pop()
    
    append(" to see everything we offer.")
}
Column {
    Text(
        text = textWithLink,
        modifier = Modifier
            .clickable { 
                // We'll handle opening the link when clicked
                println("Taking you to our website!")
            }
            .focusRequester(focusGuide)
    )
    BasicText(
        text = "Explore our latest features and updates...",
        modifier = Modifier
            .focusRequester(focusGuide)
            .clickable { /* Handle when this text is clicked */ }
            .padding(top = 16.dp)
    )
}
}


This does not work as expected. The hardware keyboard focus still focuses the complete text instead of individual annotated strings
